# Regex for "All the digits should not be same for a mobile number"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, regex

Editted: I am new to regular expressions. I need a regex for a 10-digit mobile number which should not start with 0 or 1 and the same number cannot be repeated for all 10 digits. 
Sorry for the lack of information. Please help for this problem.

Please find the html code.

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <label>Mobile Phone</label>
                                    <input id="" type="text" ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" name="mobilePhone"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           ng-model="patientIn.addressList[0].phoneNumbers['mobile']"
                                           ng-change="setPhoneNumber('mobile')"
                                           ui-mask-placeholder-char="space"
                                           model-view-value="true"/>
                                    <p ng-show="(frmPatientEdit.$submitted && frmPatientEdit.mobilePhone.$invalid) || (frmPatientEdit.mobilePhone.$invalid && frmPatientEdit.mobilePhone.$touched)"
                                       class="error">Mobile Phone is Invalid.</p>
```

Comment: My mobile number contains the sequence 6363, are you saying it's not valid? For that matter, my number contains 11 digits...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think OP means that you can't enter "0000000000" as valid number (so 10 times the same char). Also, different countries have different mobile number lengths ;)

Comment: Not an asnwer as I am no regex expert but I find this site useful for figuring regexes http://regexr.com/ I also don't think regex is the answer as it works sequentially and so would probably detect 11223344 as invalid too.

Comment: @Jordumus Oh... Yes, reading again I can see how I got mixed up there. Fair enough. I'm also guessing from the `ui-mask` that this is only accepting US phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to check if all the numbers are the same.

`(\d)` is a capturing group, `\1` matches against the capturing group `{9}` matches `\1` 9 times, you can edit that figure to suit. So This will tell you if ten numbers are the same.

```
(\d)\1{9}
```

JS

```
text.match(/(\d)\1{9}/g);
```

http://regexr.com/3efqd

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the mobile number is of format (9999) 999-9999
Hence , the regex should be

```
/\((\d)\1{3}\) \1{3}-\1{4}/.test("(9999) 999-9999")
"true"

/\((\d)\1{3}\) \1{3}-\1{4}/.test("(9999) 929-9999")
"false"
```

here, the split-up explanation of the regex is

`\(`   -> matches the ( in your string

`(\d)` -> matches the first integer and capture it (so that we could backreference it later)

`\1`  -> picks the first captured element

`{3}` -> checks if the capture is repeating 3 times

`(space)` -> space

`\1{3}` -> checks if the capture is repeating 3 times(backreferencing)

`-` -> checks for hiphen

`\1{4}` -> checks if the capture is repeating 4 times

Comment: Sorry I need to update my problem again.. The solution provide by you works fine. But the problem is I need a regex for a 10-digit mobile number which should not start with 0 or 1. Plus the same number cannot be repeated for all 10 digits. My fault. If you can get this solution it would be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class regex {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String regex1 = "(\\d)\\1{9}";
    String regex2 = "[\\d]{10}";
    Scanner ssc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter string:");
    String input = ssc.next();
    System.out.println(input.matches(regex2)&&(!input.matches(regex1)));

}
}
```

Comment: What question are you answering? They ask for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any formatting like a separators (`-`) you can use as follows

```
^([2-9])(\d{2})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})(?<!(\1{3}-\1{3}-\1{4}))$
```

This will allow first digit as only in range of `[2-9]` and phone number in format
`234-234-2345`

This also checks whether same number is used through out number.

Code break up:

```
**1st Capturing Group ([2-9])**
         Match a single character present in the list below [2-9]
         2-9 a single character in the range between 2 (index 50) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
**2nd Capturing Group (\d{2})**
        \d{2} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        {2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
 **-** 
        matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
**3rd Capturing Group (\d{3})**
        \d{3} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        {3} Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
**-** 
        matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
**4th Capturing Group (\d{4})**
       \d{4} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
       {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
**Negative Lookbehind (?<!(\1{3}-\1{3}-\1{4}))**
          Assert that the Regex below does not match
**5th Capturing Group (\1{3}-\1{3}-\1{4})**
          This group matches with character in first group at positions where 
          our format number will have digits.. i.e., it matches if same 
          number is repeated in all positions 
   
**$**
         asserts position at the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean isValidMobileNumber(String mobileNo) {
        String pattern1 = mobileNo.charAt(0) + "{10}";
        String pattern2 = "[\\d]{10}";
        return (mobileNo.matches(pattern1) ||!mobileNo.matches(pattern2)) ? false : true;
}
```