# Regular expression disallow all digits of the number to be the same

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that disallow all the same number,
and **without limitation on the length of the digits** in the number.

I'm actually looking for the **opposite** of this regex: `^(\d)\1*$`

For example:

True:
 - 111118
 - 1234
 - 88995632

False:
 - 333
 - 00000
 - 5555

I'm using ASP Regular Expression:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^(\d)\1*$" ErrorMessage="" CssClass="errfont" ControlToValidate="txtKilometer" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: By "number", do you by any chance mean "digit"? Because `333` doesn't fit otherwise...

Comment: Another Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153207/regex-for-all-the-digits-should-not-be-same-for-a-mobile-number

Comment: It's hard to tell whether the closing was relevant, depending on the (unseen) context of the question. OP, next time don't ask for just a regex, show some code.

Comment: The given questions (answers) aren't relevant, so I voted to re-open. [To do this - check this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/NdKWqv/1).

Comment: @ClasG answer was correct and I didn't find it in any of the links to the previous questions. 
Hoping that they would open the question so that it would have an official answer. Thank You!!